# How to invoke another command inside another one in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to play a specific song when typing +playtest using already defined function (+play)
but i got an error says

> "Discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
>   exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not callable"

an entire code work perfectly fine except for this command
i wonder does ctx.invoke enable passing arguments? or i just missed something

here is my brief code

```
import discord
import wavelink
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

queue = []



class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Bot, self).__init__(command_prefix=['+'])

        self.add_cog(Music(self))

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user.name} | {self.user.id}')


class Music(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        if not hasattr(bot, 'wavelink'):
            self.bot.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=self.bot)

        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.start_nodes())
        self.bot.remove_command("help")

    async def start_nodes(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        await self.bot.wavelink.initiate_node(host='127.0.0.1',
                                              port=80,
                                              rest_uri='http://127.0.0.1:80',
                                              password='testing',
                                              identifier='TEST',
                                              region='us_central')

    @commands.command(name='connect')
    async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel = None):


    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str):

    @commands.command(aliases=['sc'])
    async def soundcloud(self, ctx, *, query: str):


    @commands.command()
    async def leave(self, ctx):

    @commands.command(aliases=['queue', 'q'])
    async def check_queue(self, ctx):

    @commands.command(aliases=['clearq', 'clearqueue'])
    async def clear_queue(self, ctx):


    @commands.command(aliases=['removequeue', 'removeq', 'req'])
    async def remove_queue(self, ctx, num: int):

    @commands.command()
    async def skip(self, ctx):


    @commands.command(aliases=['eq'])
    async def equalizer(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, equalizer: str):

    @commands.command()
    async def playtest(self,ctx):
       await ctx.invoke(self.play('hi'))

bot = Bot()
bot.run('sd')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ctx.invoke does allow passing arguments, but they need to be handled in a different way to how you may be used to ( `function(params)` )

The parameters must be explicitly shown in the invoke (e.g. `param = 'value'`) and the command must be a command object.
This would be how you could invoke a command:

```
@commands.command()
async def playtest(self, ctx):
   await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('play'), query='hi')
```

Comment: is context passed automatically or do you need to specify `ctx=ctx` (I assume it does because there's essentially zero cases where you *wouldn't* want to pass context but just to clarify.

Comment: In response to my own comment: Yes, context is passed automatically