# discord.py messaging multiple people at the same time and receiving their inputs

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: I'm making a Cards Against Humanity (CAH) game with my bot to play with friends. To do this, I would like to send a message to all players given by the author as close to the same time as possible, rather than messaging them one by one and waiting for someone's input before getting the next person's input. Below is a simple, visual example I had made in case that was confusing.

[image: A visual example]

**My question**: How do I message multiple people at once and receive their separate inputs?

**Code**:

I tried to separate it using multiple commands, via [`ctx.invoke`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62461874/14420546), so the bot would run the command per person. However, instead of doing what I had expected and messaging them as it went through the list individually, the bot stopped between each person and waited for their input before sending the message to the next person.

```py
@client.command() # part 1: beginning the command sequence
@commands.check(check_blacklist)
async def test(ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]=None):
    if members != None:
        members.append(ctx.author)
        msg = ""
        for member in members:
            msg += f"\> {member.display_name}\n"
        await ctx.send(f"These people will be test: \n{msg}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Nobody")
        return
    await ctx.invoke(client.get_command('test2'), members=members)


@client.command() # part 2: sending messages to each person to see if their dms are open
async def test2(ctx, members):
    for member in members:
        try:
            await member.send("wa")
            await ctx.send(f"Successful wa to {member.display_name}")
            await ctx.invoke(client.get_command('test3'), member=member)
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has their dms closed or is a bot :pensive:")

@client.command() # part 3: receiving inputs from each person
async def test3(ctx, member:discord.Member):        
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author==member and str(msg.channel.type) == "private"
    await member.send("Please provide an input:")
    try:
        response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=75)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} didn't respond :pensive:")
        return
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}: {response.content}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use asynchronous functions that aren't commands along with [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

```
def is_dm_check(member):
    def inner_check(msg):
        return msg.author.id==member.id and msg.guild is None
    return inner_check

async def get_input(member):
    await member.send("Please provide an input:")
    return client.wait_for('message', check=is_dm_check(member), timeout=75)

@client.command()
async def play_game(ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]=None):
    if not members:
        await ctx.send("No Players")
        return
    responses = asyncio.gather(*map(get_input, members))
    for member, response in zip(members, responses):
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}: {response.content}")
```

Comment: After reading the asyncio docs linked the method said: `Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10`

Comment: Not the method, but the `loop` parameter