# Calling a discord bot function in another function

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a vote kick bot that kicks a user once a certain number of votes are counted. I want to call the kick function inside the votekick function. I am just learning python and discord bots. I have looked through the documentation for a few hours and can't figure it out.

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, Reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=Reason)
    await ctx.send('[+] Noah has been successfully kicked')

@client.command()
async def votekick(ctx):
    global vote_started
    if not vote_started:
        vote_started = True
        # await ctx.channel.send('[+] A votekick has started')
        users_voted.append(ctx.author.id)
    else: # checks to see if user has already voted
        for user in users_voted:
            if not ctx.author.id == user:
                users_voted.append(ctx.author.id)
            else:
                await ctx.send('Error: You have already voted.')
    if len(users_voted) == 1:
        # here is where I want to call kick function
```

How am I able to call the kick command inside the votekick command?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py how to invoke another command inside another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460182/discord-py-how-to-invoke-another-command-inside-another-one)

Comment: Would it screw things up if vote kick had ```async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, Reason=None):```?

Comment: @SuperStormer I've seen this post and I cant seem to get this to work. The person in this post uses self as an argument and when I do that, I get an error that says something along the lines of 'self is a required argument that is missing.'

Comment: @BuddyBobIII It gives me the error 'discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.' I've been getting these types of errors a lot and I'm not sure what causes them or how to fix it.